# MySQL sub-string search indexing

Tags: mysql, search, text

We do a lot of text search on one column of a MySQL table. We use the LIKE string comparison operator.

It would be much better if we could index the texts to speed up our searches, but as far as we know you can only do an indexing with whole words only.

We need to find texts even if only a portion of a word in the text matches the search text we are looking for. For example we want to find the text 'I have an orange' when we search for the text 'rang'.

MySQL should be able to work on the resulting rows, joining with other tables and ordering them.

Is there a search engine that can index in such a way?

Thank you!

Comment: https://blog.marceloaltmann.com/en-using-the-mysql-fulltext-index-search-pt-utilizando-mysql-fulltext/

Comment: The only builtin feature for complex search is full text, but it's geared towards natural language. Otherwise, you may need to use a third-party search server like e.g. [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: I have used the full text for a lot of things.  It works well.  Just my opinion.